# Как правильно склоняется имя Лука?

Tags: склонение, ономастика, существительные

Склоняя имя Лука, я столкнулся с проблемой. По правилам имена, заканчивающиеся на "а" склоняются как существительные, следовательно должно склоняться так: И. п. — Лука, Р. п. — Лукы. Но *Лукы* не правильно, а правильно *Луки*. Почему так? Это какое-то исключение?

Если строить предложения с данным именем в родительном падеже, то оно выглядит по-разному: *тетрадь* (кого?) *Луки Ивановича*, но *родили* (кого?) *Луку Ивановича*. Почему так?

Comment: Ну вот! И я прошляпила. Много пришлось править. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Лука́ — это одушевленное существительное мужского рода, первого склонения. Такие существительные в родительном падеже единственного числа имеют окончания **-и** или **-ы**.
Родить, видеть, терпеть (кого? что?) — это не родительный, а винительный падеж.

И. п. — Лука, Гога, Миха, юнга, владыка, парнишка.
Р. п. — Луки, Гоги, Михи, юнги, владыки, парнишки.
Д. п. — Луке, Гоге, Михе, юнге, владыке, парнишке.
В. п. — Луку, Гогу, Миху, юнгу, владыку, парнишку.
Т. п. — Лукой, Гогой, Михой, юнгой, владыкой, парнишкой.
П. п. — Луке, Гоге, Михе, юнге, владыке, парнишке.

[Существительные первого склонения](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/sushhestvitelnoe/pervoe-sklonenie-imen-suschestvitelnyh.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Почему не *Лукы?***

Действительно, окончания существительных 1-го склонения в Р.п.
***Ы/И***, что соответствует **мягкой и твердой** основе: ***гора — горы, земля — земли***, но ***Лука — Луки***.

Здесь происходит **чередование** твердого и мягкого согласного, так как сочетания **заднеязычных** согласных Г, К, Х с гласным Ы (***ГЫ, КЫ, ХЫ***) **нехарактерны** для русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший ответ о склонениях есть здесь: http://sklonenie-slova.ru/mujskie_imena/luka

Имена в целом являются некоторым исключением из общепринятых правил, поэтому мы сталкиваемся с именами, которые не склоняются совсем.
Это старорусское имя, наверное, вам будет интересно ознакомиться с его историей :)

Здесь вы найдёте полный морфологический разбор: https://pishugramotno.ru/morfologiya/%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Ссылки — вещь ненадёжная. Конкретному вопросу нужен и ответ такой же. К чему слова о разборе, коль скоро вопрос о склонении, и к чему упоминание о несклоняемых именах?

Comment: Из Справки: «Ссылки на внешние ресурсы – это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе с ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он (будет) недоступен или навсегда закрыт».

Answer (score 1):

Почему не «Лукы»? Потому что не «строкы»)))